# How to use different settings.gradle files for different environments

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

**The problem**

I have two projects, **A** (ui) and **B** (background service). Project **A** has a dependency on **B**. Project **B** gets published to a maven repository and included in project **A** like so in `build.gradle`

```
debugImplementation ('com.example:project-B:0.0.0-SNAPSHOT') { changing = true }
releaseImplementation ('com.example:project-B:1.6.2')
```

This works, but it's a pain to validate my service changes on the UI side. I need to publish project **B** to my nexus repo and resync project **A**.

I changed project **A** to the following:

build.gradle:

```
debugImplementation project(":project-b")
```

settings.gradle:

```
include ':project-a'
include 'project-b'
project(':project-b').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, "${project-b-path}")
```

I can have all my code in one IDE window and have **A** use local instance of **B**. But the problem is this will break on my build server since there is no local **B** project, only the one on nexus.

Is there a way to configure the `settings.gradle` for release vs debug? I can just commit my changes and overwrite the file on the build server, but I want to know if there are other ways?

Answer (score 3):

You can use gradle command line to set which settings or build file should be used.

**Settings File**

```
-c, --settings-file
Specifies the settings file. For example: gradle --settings-file=somewhere/else/settings.gradle
```

**Build File**

```
-b, --build-file
Specifies the build file. For example: gradle --build-file=foo.gradle. The default is build.gradle, then build.gradle.kts, then myProjectName.gradle.
```

You can find more details here: [Gradle docs: Environment options](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/command_line_interface.html#environment_options)